# Should all the fields of a resource and its related resources be passed in a REST API PUT request?

Tags: rest, put

Let's say I have a ticket & comment resource. Tickets can have many comments. In your update endpoint `HTTP PUT /api/tickets/<ticket_id>/` , should I require the client to pass all the fields of a ticket + ALL its comments when updating a ticket?

I asked some developers and some of them said that I should just pass the fields that will be modified since its lighter, faster in terms of performance and easier to use. And some said that I should pass all the fields of a ticket + ALL its comments since PUT request should be idempotent. But my concern is when there are too many comments, the payload will be very big.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, since a PUT request should replace the entity-to-update in it's entirety. If you want to do a partial update of an entity, use a PATCH request.

Also see [the rfc](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789) for reference

> **PATCH Method for HTTP**
>
> Several applications extending the Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP)
> require a feature to do partial resource modification.
>
> The existing HTTP PUT method only allows a complete replacement of a document. This proposal adds a new HTTP method, PATCH, to modify an existing HTTP resource.

So in your situation, it's probably a lot more efficient to use a PATCH request to do a partial update.

Comment: Thanks! We're using json patch for partial updates -jsonpatch.com . Anyway, if its recommended to include all fields and all the comments in a PUT request, what if there are lots of comments? Won't it cause any issues? And there are also cases where not all the comments are available in the client side since its paginated, how would you handle that scenario?

Comment: @JohnKevinM.Basco It is not recommended to include all of an entities' properties when doing a PUT, it is *required as per the RFC*. If you don't, you're not using PUT correctly. That being said, you indeed shouldn't want to use a PUT to update a ticket with lots of comments, instead use a PATCH request and only include the properties/fields you actually need or want to update

Comment: Sorry, I was confused by what you said here "It is not recommended to include all of an entities' properties when doing a PUT, it is required as per the RFC." . Based on what I understand, it is not recommended but it is required by RFC? Can you kindly explain it further?

Comment: @JohnKevinM.Basco The RFC is the official guideline for how to use HTTP methods etc. It states that *HTTP PUT method only allows a complete replacement of a document.*. You are free to use PUT as you wish though, but using it any other way than the RFC states would be considered dirty and can cause confusion among developers

Comment: Ahh. So basically, the correct way to use PUT is to include all the properties of a ticket and all its comments, however, it is not recommended especially when there are lots of comments so its better to use a partial update via PATCH instead if you will update the properties of a ticket. Its also not recommended to use PUT for partial update since it is considered dirty and might confuse devs since its for a complete replacement of a document. Correct?

Comment: @JohnKevinM.Basco Yes, correct. I guess you could see a PUT request as a DELETE followed by a POST combined in one (in terms of what effect they should have)