# How to implement the full resource update endpoint of a resource with relationships in a REST API?

Tags: rest, http, put

Let's say I have a Ticket resource that has a relationship to Comment resource and User resource and I need to implement a full resource update endpoint using HTTP PUT for the Ticket resource.

A comment is a direct child of a ticket so it can't exist without a parent ticket.
A user can exist without a ticket since its not a direct child of a ticket.

Based on my research, the update endpoint of a resource using HTTP PUT should include all the fields of a resource and its relationships - [Should all the fields of a resource and its related resources be passed in a REST API PUT request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30118138/should-all-the-fields-of-a-resource-and-its-related-resources-be-passed-in-a-res)

Now how can I implement the update endpoint of a ticket?

If I need to pass all the comments of a ticket and the associated user, I think the code for the update endpoint of a ticket will be very complex especially if the associated comments and user also has a relationship to other resources and assuming that we are using a relational database and these resources are on separate tables. And also, the payload size will be very large.

And are there any existing examples that I can use as a reference?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sticking to what is "supposed" to be in an HTTP request at the expense of complexity is, at least in my opinion,  a pointless waste of time. It's good to try and keep it organized according to protocol, but the actual value gotten out of it is minute. Do what makes sense.

Comment: @CargoMeister I agree with you. I'm still curious how would someone implement it though in a real REST way. Currently considering a practical approach by implementing an endpoint using PUT for the resources but ignore the associations. Or don't implement an update endpoint using PUT in the scenario above and just implement the partial update endpoint using PATCH like what Github is doing if I'm not mistaken - https://developer.github.com/v3/gists/#edit-a-gist . You'll notice that an endpoint using PUT is not available.

Comment: Again, it's all just what makes sense. If you're going to retrieve a whole bunch of info, just to pass it all back down to the server again, that really doesn't make sense. If you have the data in the client, and want to avoid a bunch of costly look ups in the server, then you could pass it all down. Typically, we only pass down enough data that allows the server to do lookups and retrieve the rest of what is needed itself. We also tend to code our models so that the methods that do the updates can be called by other methods, so that they are reusable.